# Android: User select color of textView Background

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I am trying to create a menu option in which a user can select the color a textView can be displayed in. So for example the user selects red, selects a preview button which sets a textView background to red. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
public class UserMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button preview;
Spinner spinnerColor;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_menu);

        spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerColorMenu);
        TextView Title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ViewModuleTitle);

        preview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previewButton);
           preview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String color = spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color);


    }
}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ViewModuleTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkBlue"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/addModule"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lableTextModuleCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enterModuleCode"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        style="@style/textColor"/>

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerColorMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/colorMenu"/>

     <Button
          android:id="@+id/previewButton"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:onClick="previewButton"
          android:text="@string/addModule" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: knowing what the layout looks like would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
        String color = spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(color.equalsignorecase("Red"))
         {
            Title.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         }
         else if(color.equalsignorecase("Blue"))
         {
            Title.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
         }
}
```

More..

Comment: I tried a method similar to above however R.color is giving me an error:cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: do you want to change background color ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String color = spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
Title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color);
```

it doesn't work, you should use `switch (color)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:-

1. Let color_array in the colormenu.xml is as follows :-

   ```
   <item>red</item>
   <item>blue</item>
   <item>green</item>
   <item>black</item>
   ```
2. Add the following line in your onClick:-

   **int parsed_color = Color.parseColor(color);**
3. Here is the modified code:-

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button preview;

Spinner spinnerColor;

TextView Title;

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerColorMenu);
   Title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ViewModuleTitle);

    preview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previewButton);
       preview.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    String color = spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int parsed_color = Color.parseColor(color);

   Title.setBackgroundColor(parsed_color );


}
```

}

This works fine. No need of any if else statement or any switch.

**P.S. The method parseColor() supports  #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray' formats.**